# Position of QSlider in a widget

Tags: qt, qslider

I am trying to draw a line between two sliders in Qt. When I move either of the sliders, I want the line to move such that it always joins the two sliders. See attached pic[image]

(I have drawn the line for illustration - not programatically)
How do I do that? The problem is with identifying the position of the sliders. How do I get their locations? either within the widget or within the screen? Once I get their positions, I will be able to draw the line.

Any ideas? Let me know if you want me to post the code, but basically, all I have is two QSliders - one on top and one at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the Qt documentation there is a way to calculate the pixel position from the current silder value with: QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue [Qt documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstyle.html#sliderPositionFromValue)